# react-router: make auth in root route leads to stack overflow

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to make all my url is authenteication required,

so I followed the auth-flow example to adjust my code

my rootRoute:

```
var rootRoute = {
    component: 'div',
    childRoutes: [{
        onEnter: redirectToSignin,
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: require('./components/App.js'),
                indexRoute: {
                    component: require('./components/Live.js')
                },
                childRoutes: [
                    require('./routes/SignIn.js'),
                    require('./routes/SignUp.js'),
                    require('./routes/Search.js'),
                    require('./routes/Post.js'),
                    require('./routes/Share.js'),
                    require('./routes/User.js'),
                    {
                        path: '*',
                        component: require('./components/NotFound.js')
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

and then I enter http://localhost:3000, it did redirect to /signin

but nothing rendered, and it caused the error below

[image]

UPDATE:

```
function isSignedIn() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('user') !== null;
}


redirectToSignin = function(nextState, replace) {
    if (!isSignedIn()) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: {
                nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show `redirectToSignIn`?

Comment: @sma I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

`redirectToSignIn` ends up calling itself because `/signin` is a child route of the `root route`, creating an infinite loop.

Redirecting to `/login` triggers the onEnter event, which redirects to `/login` which triggers the onEnter, and on and on until your browser gets fed up.

Have you tried displaying a login form without `replace` or `push` ?